# A simple question in regards to a academic article

Tags: regression

**Introduction:**

I am currently doing some reading on psycological research and in this context I have some questions which may seem very simple. Nevertheless, it is not very transparent from the articles how the calculations are made so please feel free to answer as broad or as specific as you feel.

**Question:**

What confuses me is a statement like this:

b= -.09, t(82) = -2.14, p<.05

or this:

b= .34, t(68.87) = 2.03, p<.05

Should I consider this as the [General Linear Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model)?

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

[See this example](http://cmapspublic2.ihmc.us/rid=1LQRS9WDF-1618CKG-1L54/pdf%20%282%29.pdf)

Comment: What article(s) do you refer to? What is the model corresponding to the results you quote?

Comment: Normally, within psychology you would assume that such coefficients refer to linear regression like you say, but yes, the authors should specify at some point.

Comment: [See this example](http://cmapspublic2.ihmc.us/rid=1LQRS9WDF-1618CKG-1L54/pdf%20(2).pdf)

Comment: There is no way to know, without context. If the context doesn't tell you, then that is a serious flaw in the article.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you've linked to, the analysis is actually a [mixed model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model), with random intercepts, which is a little more complicated than the General Linear Model, but it really could have been made more clear.

> A main effects model with a random intercept was tested
>   initially (Kenny et al., 2006). The following equation was
>   tested for each emotion [...]

`Observed Emotion =  Actor’s AAI + Actor’s CAI + Partner’s AAI + Partner’s CAI + Actor’s Sex +
 Actor’s Depression + Partner’s Depression.`

Answer (score 0):

The paper you linked to tells you what general class of models were used (as will any paper worth reading):

From the abstract: "Hierarchical linear models demonstrated that ..."

p897: "we tested a series
of hierarchical linear models using Mixed SPSS 12."

And then the paper mentions *specific* models:

p897 "A main effects model with a random intercept was tested
initially (Kenny et al., 2006)"

...

This part of the paper worries me though:

p897 "Interaction effects were tested next and nonsignificant in-
teraction terms were removed to reduce the number of
predictor variables in the model."

Comment: "Hierarchical linear models demonstrated that" is not a description of the model, it is a description of a (broad) category of regression methods. But the way the OP present the stats from the paper already made that clear: these are regression model outputs. Eoin's answer provides an example of the model.

Comment: The general class of models used are hierarchical linear models, which is what I claimed. If Eoin's answer is better, you really should upvote it.